# Visual Studio 2010 "Publish" does not copy Razor view files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, razor

When using the built-in Publish feature of Visual Studio 2010 with a web application that includes Razor views (.cshtml or .vbhtml), **the publish service does not copy the Razor view files**.

This occurs both on a local "File System" publish as well as a remote publish using Web Deploy, using the [November 9 Release Candidate](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx).

Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: The "Build Action" property of the project item is relevant.  Try "Content" so that the IDE knows that it is an item that needs to be deployed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to set the build action to "Content" under properties.

Edit: You have to do this on each of the files that aren't being copied over.

Edit 2: I did some poking around, and found a forum posting over at msdn, sounds like you can edit the registry, or create a pkdef file.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsxprerelease/thread/c0212d15-96c4-455d-b7e1-d299c5ef384a

Comment: +1 this is a "known workaround" but by-golly I hope it's not the only one!

Comment: MVC 3 RC seems to have fixed this particular issue.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed fixed with ASP.NET MVC 3 RC because there is now full Visual Studio support for Razor.

Comment: I'm having this issue with MVC 3 RC.

Comment: I thought I had the issue with MVC3 RC but I realized that I only had issues with the views that I created while I was using the beta version, the newly created views are ok

Comment: The MS Department of Bad Defaults has not fixed this in vs 2012

Comment: This happened to me just today, even in VS 2013.  I had an HTML file to begin with that I renamed to be a .cshtml file and it was not being deployed.  I had to manually change the build action to 'content'.

Answer (score 10):

(This answer is mostly if someone finds this through google etc)

As @Ted Ballou pointed out you need to change output type to Content. This can be quite cumbersome if you, like me, have 100+ files in different subfolders.

Especially since you can't update multiple files at once if there's a folder included in the selection.

Instead of changing through the GUI, open the project file and modify the settings directly.

In `YourProject.csproj` change  items like:

`<None Include="Views\Foo\Bar.cshtml />`

to

```
<Content Include="Views\Foo\Bar.cshtml" />
```

I used the following Regular Expression to replace all files:

Search for: `<None Include="(.+)\.cshtml" />`

Replace with: `<Content Include="$1.cshtml" />`

Now Visual Studio should treat all your changed cshtml as `Content` on publish.