# Visual Studio has stopped "Publishing" all of my Views since moving to MVC3 and Razor

Tags: visual-studio, publishing, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010 "Publish" does not copy Razor view files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146806/visual-studio-2010-publish-does-not-copy-razor-view-files)

I use the "Publish" feature to push the required files to my staging server.  Since the staging server is in house, I use a mapped drive and just publish to the file system. The settings are set to

> Only files needed to run this application
>   Exclude generated debug symbols

When I use using MVC2 and the WebForms view engine, the publish always worked.

Now that I'm using the Razor view engine and MVC3 RC1, only about half of my Views get published to the file system.  Everything else (Assets, web.Config, App_Browsers, and Bin) gets published as expected.  What could be the problem here?

After seeing this question, it appears as though it's a problem with the "Build Action"
[Visual Studio 2010 "Publish" does not copy Razor view files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146806/visual-studio-2010-publish-does-not-copy-razor-view-files)

Unfortunately, the answer says it's been fixed in MVC3 RC, but unfortunately this is what I'm experiencing, and I'm using the RC.

Comment: Not quite a dup.  The answer on the other page says that this is fixed in MVC3 RC.  But I'm running MVC3 RC and it's not fixed. Could this be a different problem?

Comment: Well, unless you provide more details, it does sound like a dup. Did you make sure all of your views that are not being published do have the build action set as `Content`?

Comment: I looked into it and it appears as though the build action was not set to Content. But why would it be happening in MVC3 RC when they say the issue is fixed?

Comment: Did you start with a brand new project or are you using a project created with the Beta?

Comment: It's an MVC2 project that i migrated.  I never use Beta releases.